# Why do js functions fail when I assign them to a local variable?

Tags: clojurescript

In clojurescript 1.9.89 and Chrome 50.0.2661.102, I can create a log statement like:

```
(js/console.log "works")
```

But I can't create one like:

```
(def brokenlog js/console.log)
(brokenlog "but not here")

--> #object[TypeError TypeError: Illegal invocation]
```

When I try to compare these approaches by printing the value of my own `brokenlog` function, it looks just like the "real one" -- that is, both `brokenlog` and `js/console.log` evaluate for me as:

```
#object[log "function log() { [native code] }"]
```

Similarly, I see this behavior with:

```
cljs.user=> (js/document.querySelector "body")
#object[HTMLBodyElement [object HTMLBodyElement]]
cljs.user=> (def l js/document.querySelector)
#'cljs.user/l
cljs.user=> (l "body")
#object[TypeError TypeError: Illegal invocation]
nil
```

Upgrading to Chrome 52 fixes the `console.log` behavior, but not the `document.querySelector` behavior.

So I have two questions:

#### 1. What am I missing

#### 2. Where are the official docs I should be reading that would explain it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which browser and clojurescript version you are using?
the following code should work on your browser if it display *nil* into box.

```css
.as-console-wrapper .as-console {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<pre><code class="language-klipse">
(js/console.log "Work!")
(def brokenlog js/console.log)
(brokenlog "Work again!")
; two line should be seen in your browser log
</code></pre>
<script>
    window.klipse_settings = {
        selector: '.language-klipse', // css selector for the html elements you want to klipsify
    };
</script>
<script src="http://app.klipse.tech/plugin/js/klipse_plugin.js?"></script>
<link href="http://app.klipse.tech/css/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

*EDIT*

Here is the clojurescript

```
(ns hello-world.core)
(def mylog js/console.log)
(mylog "Hello")
```

compiled to javascript

```
hello_world.core.mylog = console.log;
hello_world.core.mylog.call(null,"Hello");
```

*console.log.call(null, ....)* trigger the chrome bug, console.log expecting `this` is the `console` object. It should be fixed as mentioned in the issue log https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167911.

Comment: I've updated my question to specify versions -- the issue is with clojurescript 1.9.89 and Chrome 50.0.2661.102,

Comment: It should be a chrome specific bug which fixed at about Apr 2016. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167911

Comment: This same behavior and error  occurrs with any js function I try (e.g.  document.querySelector) -- so I don't think the console.log bug explains it.

Comment: Ah, the compiled code explains this very clearly -- thanks!