# Use apply on native JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

In clojureScript the following multi-arity function

```
(defn sum [& xs] (reduce + xs))
```

can be either called via `(sum 4 6 9)` or by the use of `(apply sum [4 6 9])` which yields the same result.

How can this be done with a native JavaScript function, such as: `console.log`.

```
(apply js/console.log [1 2 3])
```

This, yields the following error:

```
#object[TypeError TypeError: 'log' called on an object that does not implement interface Console.]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about clojureScript, but in JS you need `console.log.apply(console, […])` to make it work (though it's browser-specific)

Comment: hmm... this is interesting.  In planck (osx clojurescript repl) I tried this out and it worked fine.  `(apply js/console.log [1 2 3])` and `(js/console.log 1 2 3)` both print `1` and return `nil`

Comment: this has gotta be some browser-specific thing.  I just fired up a minimal figwheel project (from this template: https://github.com/bhauman/figwheel-template ) and sent `(apply js/console.log [1 2 3])` to the browser from the figwheel repl; it logged `1 2 3` --- I'm using a current version of Chrome, what are you using?

Comment: just to make sure this isn't an implementation difference on the javascript side in whatever environment you're using, what happens when you try `(apply js/Math.sqrt [25])`?  It should return 5 without a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some browsers always assuming the `this` is certain object, you can use `.bind` in js for temporal fix.

```
; you can use .bind on any function
(def d (.bind (.-log js/console) js/console))
(def ms ["aaa" "bbb" "barbarbar"])
(mapv d ms)
```

### Related questions

[What does this statement do? console.log.bind(console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668759/what-does-this-statement-do-console-log-bindconsole)

[Why do js functions fail when I assign them to a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934406/why-do-js-functions-fail-when-i-assign-them-to-a-local-variable)

Answer (score 2):

There might be an error in your code. `apply` works totally fine out of the box for JS functions:

```
cljs.user=> (apply js/Math.sqrt [25])
5
```

You can test it with this [online REPL](http://clojurescript.net/) and I also tested it in my local project -- no problems so far.

```
cljs.user=> (apply js/console.log [1 2 3])
nil
```

also prints the output in the normal JS console as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using `js/a.b` only works when `a` is global in your environment. Either way, I find this much cleaner:

```
(apply (.-log js/console) [1 2 3])
```

Note: with member functions, don't forget the first argument is `this`.